# how to convert pdf to pksmraw by using ghostscript in android system?the error code is -15

Tags: android, pdf, ghostscript

I want to convert pdf to pksmraw by using `ghostscript9.04`, the command is:

```
gs -q -dBATCH -dSAFER -dQUIET -dNOPAUSE -sPAPERSIZE=a4 -r300x300 -sDEVICE=pksmraw -sOutputFile=printjob.pksmraw printjob.pdf
```

But in android system, it's no output, and the error code is -15.

I think it's maybe Resources and libs is can't be found.

So in android system, how to set up the Resources and libs?

Comment: Hey just asking, how did you compile ghostscript for android

Answer (score 1):

error code -15 is a rangecheck error. In order to find out more you are going to have to find out where stdout and stderr are going, and capture them.

We don't supply Ghostscript for Android systems, so I assume you built this yourself, in which case it should be reasonably straight-forward for you to figure out where the error messages are going.

Oh, the current version is 9.10, you might well want to upgrade too.

Library and resource files are ordinarily built into the executable using a rom file system, unless you specified COMPILE_INITS=0 at build time.

Answer (score 0):

Try this example

```
gs \
 -sDEVICE=pdfwrite \
 -o foo.pdf \
  /usr/local/share/ghostscript/8.71/lib/viewjpeg.ps \
 -c \(my.jpg\) viewJPEG
reads my.jpg and produces foo.pdf. You will have to find where your installation installed the PostScript program viewjpeg.ps.
```

Same way do it for to convert pdf to pksmraw it will work for you.